# Calculate difference in two date column (having nan value ) in HH:MM:SS format in pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan, datetime-format

I have 2 columns  in a dataframe. I want to calculate the difference of  2 columns in hh:mm:ss and write the result into a new column

```
Input

Planned Pickup date/time    Actual Pickup date/time      
07/05/2018 09:28:00         07/05/2018 09:33:15               
14/05/2018 17:00:00         15/05/2018 08:44:08               
15/05/2018 17:00:00         15/05/2018 10:52:50              
15/05/2018 17:00:00         15/05/2018 15:03:34             
15/05/2018 17:00:00         Nan              
16/05/2018 17:00:00         16/05/2018 16:00:38
```

I want to calculate the difference the actual and  planned pickup  in hh:mm:ss and write the result into a new column in dataframe called  `data['time difference']`

How can this done in pandas

Comment: convert both columns to datetime and simply substract them

Comment: If all values are `time` use -> `df = df.applymap(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))` or `df = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))` and then `df['Planned Pickup date/time'] - df['Actual Pickup date/time'] `

Comment: How do you expect to handle directionality? IE row 3 (index 2) was picked up 8ish hours early. Do you want the absolute time difference or something like -8 hours?

Comment: i want in hh:mm:ss format. "df['Planned Pickup date/time'] - df['Actual Pickup date/time']" this gives in number of days  HH:mm:ss format.i want days to convert into hhmmss

Comment: if difference is more than 24 hrs.it gives days and hhmmss.i want only in hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas .this helped me.i converted  time difference in seconds.and seconds converted into hh:mm:ss